# Custom grid in firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

We are merging current vcl applications to Firemonkey.  The current biggest issue is to create a tgrid with some custom columns.

I need a column with a combobox cells as well as a column with multiple check boxes in each cell.

Answer (score 0):

**Any solution that overrides the CreateCellControl method of the TColumn class does NOT work anymore**. 
The new API provides an class called TGridModel, which through the OnCreateCustomEditor event allows you to dynamically create the editing components of a grid cell. However I still could not find any examples using this method.

```
procedure TForm1.MyOnCreateCustomEditor(Sender: TObject; const Column: TColumn; var Control: TStyledControl);
var
  idx: Integer;
begin
  idx := Column.Model.IndexOfColumn(Column);
  case idx of
    // Create controls here
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.OnCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inherited;
  Grid1.Model.OnCreateCustomEditor := MyOnCreateCustomEditor;
end;
```